# Rails 4 Application performing unexpected redirect once deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, controller

I have a Rails 4 form that is submitted via ajax, and should respond with a json object on either success or failure - but for some strange reason it conducts a redirect after saving to the db and storing the flash message.

```
  def update
    success = lambda do |financing, message|
      flash[:success] = message
      track("Updated", { :customer_id => customer.id, :object_id => financing.id })
      render :status => 200, :json => { message: message, next_url: customer_objects_path }
    end

    failure = lambda do |form|
      @object = form
      render :status => 400, :json => { :errors => form.errors }
    end

    ::Actions::Object::EditObject.new(object_params).execute(success, failure, attributes)
  end
```

That is the controller method. The actions parameter runs the update and then calls success, and it appears that the redirect happens after `flash[:success] = message` and before the `track` call.

Also, this is completely not reproducible on my local machine in the development environment, but can only be reproduced on staging. I ran with the staging environment on my local machine, and was able to reproduce the error, but when I stepped through with `byebug`, it worked fine, so at this point, I'm not sure where to poke next.

Comment: Is it working fine without `flash[:success] = message`?

Comment: just checked and no it is not. (it works on my local machine if i run it with the staging env, but isn't working when i deploy to staging)

Comment: Check if you have the right branch deployed?

Comment: ^ done that many times. - i ssh'ed into the machine and checked what files were deployed, everything was kosher

Comment: correction. the code has been updated, but for some reason the flash message is still set

Comment: Can you include the log for the action in your question?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill sure